# How to save a image in my magento module

Tags: magento-1.9

I had created a checkboxes like isLab and isFood.

When i check isLab the image is saving.But when i uncheck isLab checkbox the image is not saving.

Before adding these checkboxes there is no problem with image saving.After adding these checkboxes there is an issue with image saving

Can anybody help me how to save an image. I need it very soon.

Comment: can anybody help me to solve my problem

Comment: Add Log before "if(isset($_FILES['serviceprovider_image']['name']) && $_FILES['serviceprovider_image']['name'] != '')" line:

Comment: it is not working.it is showing an empty page if i add Log

Comment: use this : Mage::log(print_r($_FILES,true),null,'image.log');
Check Log Here : var/log/image.log

Answer (score 2):

When you want to save an image, your form has to have this attribute:

```
enctype = 'multipart/form-data'
```

Instantiate the form like this:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
```

and then add the field like this:

```
$fieldset->addField(‘image', 'file', array(
'label' => Mage::helper(‘module')->__(‘label'),
'name' => 'image',
));
```

Other than that - check if you have your directory created:

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'serviceprovider' . DS;
```

Comment: i tried with that but the image is broken after selecting another checkbox.The path is created as mentioned above.

Comment: helloo can anyone help me please.I need it very soon.The image is broken when i select another checkbox

Comment: Just to confirm.. is the image saved in the path that you provide to the uploader?

Comment: yes the image is saved in the path

Comment: So what do you mean by "the image is broken", is the file damaged?